# How to expose provider to screen. (Provider to expose only available on previous screen)

Tags: flutter

I have 2 providers, `Product` and `Products`.

3 screens and 1 widget, a `ProductsScreen` that list all products with a `ListView.builder` with the widget as its child, a `ProductDetailScreen` that shows a single product details and a `ProductEditScreen` to edit a product.

I expose the `Products` provider on main, and the `Product` provider to each item in the `ListView`.
The user can go to `ProductEditScreen` on `ProductsScreen` and on `ProductDetailScreen`.

With the code I have now if user goes to edit on the `ProductsScreen`, edits the product and saves, the app goes back to `ProductsScreen` and the edited product shows the correct data.

I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to expose the `Product` provider to `ProductDetailScreen`. I need the `product` provider also here because if user goes to product edit and saves, the app goes back I need to show the correct product data.

`main.dart`

```
...
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (ctx) => Products(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'My app',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
          accentColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        ),
        initialRoute: ProductsScreen.routeName,
        routes: {
          ProductsScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductsScreen(),
          ProductDetailScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductDetailScreen(),
          ProductEditScreen.routeName: (ctx) => ProductEditScreen(),
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`products_screen.dart`

```
...
class ProductsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/products-screen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final products = Provider.of<Products>(context, listen: true);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Products'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: products.items.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, idx) => ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: products.items[idx],
          child: ProductItemWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`product_item_widget.dart`

```
...
class ProductItemWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final product = Provider.of<Product>(context);
    return Card(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: product.image.isEmpty
            ? Icon(Icons.image)
            : Image.asset(product.image),
        title: Text(product.name),
        subtitle: Text(product.info),
        trailing: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.edit),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                  ProductEditScreen.routeName,
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
            ProductDetailScreen.routeName,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Provider.of<Products>(context)` in `ProductDetailScreen`, can't you? or Am I missing something here?

Comment: Yes, but in that case I would have to pass the product index to `ProductItemWidget` and then to `ProductDetailScreen` to access the correct product. That could work, but is this the best option?

Comment: Got your issue. You may try creating a new field in `Product` class, `selectedProductId` and set it when item is selected. When you set it calling `notifyListeners` will update the ui